# Laptop Battery charging only when switched off

Tags: windows-10, window

I was using my laptop Sattelite C660-1E2 for around three years. Now, the battery is not charging while the laptop is on/working.  It is only charged when the laptop is  switched off.
what will be the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Generally this is caused by the laptop not receiving enough power. Your power supply might need to be replaced.

https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=Sattelite+C660-1E2+power+cable

Does the DC Jack on the laptop feel loose? Do you have a way to do a health check on the battery? When you go into your BIOS does it show being plugged in? (You can get there by pressing the F2 key at startup)

Comment: Thank you for your sugestion. I also tried by the charger you proposed me there is no change.